# Better file naming conventions or structure

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create folders and then add files e.g.

```
folder: orders
files : view.php, add_update.php, invoice.php
Uri becomes: orders/view, orders/add_update, orders/invoice
```

another example

```
folder: user
files : view.php (view profile), add_update.php (add, update users)
Uri   : users/view, users/add_update
```

and many more folders and files having similar structure. It works fine but in the editor (netbeans) I see the the name of the file only in the tab so that if I have opened `order/view.php, users/view.php, files/view.php` I see `view.php, view.php, view.php` ... I can certainly hover over and see the full path but I was wondering if you guys follow a better file naming pattern. I sometime make mistakes when uploading `orders/view.php  or users/view.php` cos the files structure look so similar. What would you suggest?

PS: These are controllers not the CI view files. One of the reasons I have this structure is to have meaningful uri. I just tagged in CI but it doesn't matter if I am using CI or not.

Comment: I honestly dont understand what is your question. If you named the structure yourself, and you wanted to create folders for controllers for meaningful purposes; considering that you're the coder who created the folders, I dont see how you're making mistakes.

Comment: But on the other hand, you might want to take a look at CI routes to remove some of the unnecessary "folder names" in the URI. if thats what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Why the need for folders? Why not simply have a class of `Orders`with methods `view`, `update`, etc?

Barebones example:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

class Orders extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

/* URL = example.com/orders */
function index()
{

    /* default action */
}

/* URL = example.com/orders/view */
function view()
{
    /* view method code */
}

/* etc */

}
```

Comment: 1. it's more complex for just putting it all in a single class.. 2. folders help organise as its a big project

Comment: You need an entire class just to generate a user's profile view? And another whole class simply to update a user? Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename your files like order_view.php, order_update.php etc and similarly user_view.php, user_update.php... it will differentiate the orders and users in your IDE

Comment: so the url becomes users/user_edit etc - I have already tried that in the past.

Comment: u can change the url by using your routing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with namespaces, and give the views a more meaningful name.

This is how my Netbeans looks:

[image]

And I have assigned namespace `\Ganymedes\Views` to all of them. So I have meaningful names, and still everything in the same namespace.

Comment: sorry my question is about controllers. I am not bothered about views filenames as they don't affect uri. I keep view files in their own folders too e.g. user/edit.php - and I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: Obvious, for controllers it is exactly the same, just replace Views for Controllers!!